# Count the total number of records for a particular time stamp

Tags: sum, db2, grouping

Hi I need to construct an DB2/SQL Query in order to know the total number of items for a respective time stamp.

```
      Date            Item
 01/08/2014 05:53   request 1 
 02/08/2014 05:53   request 1
 03/08/2014 05:53   request 1
 01/08/2014 06:32   request 2
 02/08/2014 06:32   request 2
 03/08/2014 06:32   request 2
 01/08/2014 06:38   request 3
 02/08/2014 06:38   request 3
 03/08/2014 06:38   request 3
 04/08/2014 06:38   request 3
 05/08/2014 06:38   request 3
```

I wish to have the output to be in this manner:

```
         Date             Item       No of Occurences
    01/08/2014 05:53    request 1           3
    01/08/2014 06:32    request 2           3
    01/08/2014 06:38    request 3           5
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Include Date in the grouping also:

```
SELECT Date, Item, count(*) as "No of Occurrences"
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY Date, Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

```
   SELECT Date, Item, Count(*) "No of Occurences"
   FROM <Table>
   GROUP BY Item
```